# Flattening object of arrays to one array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, asp.net-web-api

I'm working on that scenario:

I'm calling an `API`, based on item selected from drop-down list, the URL changes,

all the APIs has the same signature of the GET action, so changing the URL of the controller will go to a specific `GetAll()` action

in those APIs, the returned data are not in the same signature: I have three signatures:

```
return data; // data is a List<object>

return new {data = list}; //list is a List<object>

return new {data = list, Count = list.Count()};
```

unfortunatly I can't change the signature because a lot of client side scripts will break.

In my angular controller I run this code:

```
GenericService.getCategories(catApi).then(function (categories) { //catApi is the API URL of the selected entity
    if (categories == null)
        $scope.cats = null;
    else
        $scope.cats = categories.data; //works only for returned List
```

getCategories function:

```
this.getCategories = function (categoryApi) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var list = [];
    var count = 0;

    $http({
        url: '/api/' + categoryApi,
        method: 'GET',
        params: {}
    }).success(function (result) {
        list = result;
        deferred.resolve({
            data: list,
        });
    }).error(deferred.reject);

    return deferred.promise;
};
```

I then use `$scope.cats` to loop through the items in the list using `ng-repeat`.

Is there any workaround to this, given that I only know the name of array returned (as an array or as a property of object)?

Comment: Do you try to iterate through returned object properties?

Comment: If it was object, I want to iterate through the array inside, and if it was an array iterate through it directly.

Comment: Not entirely sure of what you want but it looks like it's something related with [Array.isArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)